# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i=1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^{2}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i=1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^{2}=0$?

If it is true, then can you help prove it?

Comment: $(1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: So is $\frac12, \frac14, \frac18,\dots$

Comment: Heck... we can do better... if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_i=1$ then we can actually prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_i^2$ is **not** equal to zero.  Really... if you had tried **any** example then you would have found the statement as written was untrue.

Comment: Another example to add: $w_k=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k\log2}$;  $\sum_{k\geqslant1} w_k=1$,  $\sum_{k\geqslant1} w^2_k=\frac{\pi^2}{6\log^22}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. $$\sum_1^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^n = 1,$$ but $$\sum_1^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^{2n} = \sum_1^\infty (\frac{1}{4})^n = \frac{1}{3} \neq 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Even more important of an example to note...

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \approx -0.605$$

Letting the exact value of the above be $\alpha$ then

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha \sqrt{n}}=1$$

Yet if we were to square everything:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\alpha^2 n}=\infty$$

Squaring termwise doesn't even necessarily retain convergence!